# In C++ how to find an int in a string

Tags: c++

I want to do this if its possible, 

`char buff[]="MA A8C : B12A : D14C: ... etc."
int myId=12;
if (myId exist in Buff){print i found it}else{it doesn't not exist}`

so simply i want to indicate that this integer does exist in this string, i don't need position or where or how many time it is mentioned or anything complicated,,, all my searches lead to someone trying to find where this int is ... but in my case i just want to find IS IT THERE return 1 not there? return 0. and Thanks

Comment: Convert that int into a string, and from that point - simple textual search.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius What if you want to find number 1 and the text contains the number 12?

Comment: @NeilKirk So, technically, the text contains the following numbers: '1', '2', '12'.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that directly. You can convert the number to a string first and search for the string in `buff`.

You can use a C approach:

```
char temp[10];
sprintf(temp, "%d", myId);
if ( strstr(buff, temp) != NULL )
{
   // Found it.
}
else
{
   // Did not find it.
}
```

If you want to use more of a C++ approach, you can use:

```
auto found = std::string(buff).find(std::to_string(myID));
if ( found != std::string::npos )
{
   // Found it.
}
else
{
   // Did not find it.
}
```

Comment: What if you want to find number 1 and the text contains the number 12?

Comment: @NeilKirk, that will be a problem. If that's a scenario that is likely to happen, the OP has to change strategies.

Comment: Thanks Allot, it worked like magic. no loops and no pain .... thanks god i didn't need to study python to solve this big problem, Thanks sir